Is possibile to define transfinite sum and product recursively?
On mathstackexchange a few days ago I published the following question where I asked about "transfinite" sum and products but actually nobody answered or gave an opinion with a comment: thus I thought this is a niche argument so that I revised the post adding more details and explanations hoping I can seek help here.
I know it is possibile to define finite sum of ordinals: if $(\alpha_i)_{i\in n}$ is a sequence of lenght $n$, with $n$ in $\omega$, then the symbolisms $\sum_{i\in n}\alpha_i$ and $\prod_{i\in n}\alpha_i$ have a (formal) meaning; however, I did not find any text or article which attributes a (formal) meaning to the symbolisms $\sum_{i\in\omega_1}\alpha_i$ and $\prod_{i\in\omega_1}\alpha_i$, where $\alpha_i$ is an ordinal for any $i$ in $\omega_1$: to be precisely into the textes Cardinal and ordinal numbers by Sierpiński and Linear Ordering by Rosenstein I found a definition using order types but I am searching for a recursive solution so that I elaborated the following lemma, hoping it allows to define a "transfinite" sum.
To follow I will indicate with $\mathbf{Ord}$ and $\mathbf{Lim}_+$ the class of ordinals and the calss of not empty limit ordinals; moreover, if the property $\mathbf P$ is any functional (into the set class) then I will say that the corresponding "function" is a class-function.

Lemma
Let be $\xi$ a (not empty) transfinite sequence of lenght $\lambda$ with range a set of ordinals $X$ and thus let be $\bot$ an operation in $\mathbf{Ord}$: there exists a unique class-function $\pmb\bot_\xi$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that the equality
\begin{equation}
\pmb\bot_\xi(0)=
\begin{cases}
\xi(0),\text{ if $\xi\neq\emptyset$}\\
\emptyset,\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
\label{eq: zero case}
\end{equation}
holds like for any ordinal $\alpha$ the equality
\begin{equation}
\pmb\bot_\xi(\alpha+1)=
\begin{cases}
\pmb\bot_\xi(\alpha)\,\bot\,\,\xi(\alpha+1),\text{if $\alpha+1<\lambda$}\\
\pmb\bot_\xi(\alpha),\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
\label{eq: successive case}
\end{equation}
and the equality
\begin{equation}
\pmb\bot_\xi(\alpha)=\sup_{\beta\in\alpha}\pmb\bot_\xi(\beta)
\tag{3}
\label{eq: limit case}
\end{equation}
whether $\alpha$ is in $\mathbf{Lim}_+$
Proof.
Firstly, if $h$ is a function with domain an ordinal $\alpha$ and range an ordinal set $X$ then to follow let's we call it (ordinal) calculus of lenght $\alpha$ or more briefly $\alpha$-calculus. So let be $\mathbf P$ the property which is true when one of the following sentences is it:
(a) $h$ is a $0$-calculus and the equality
\begin{equation}
k=
\begin{cases}
\xi(0),\text{ if $\xi\neq\emptyset$}\\
\emptyset,\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\tag{4}
\label{eq: P zero}
\end{equation}
holds;
(b) $h$ is an $(\alpha+1)$-calculus, with $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$, such that the equality
\begin{equation}
k=
\begin{cases}
h(\alpha)\,\bot\,\,\xi(\alpha+1),\text{ if $\alpha+1<\lambda$}\\
h(\alpha),\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\tag{5}
\label{eq: P successive}
\end{equation}
holds;
(c) $h$ is an $\alpha$ calculus, with $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Lim}_+$, such that the equality
\begin{equation}
k=\sup_{\beta\in\alpha}h(\beta)
\tag{6}
\label{eq: P limit}
\end{equation}
holds;
(d) $h$ is not an ordinal calculus and the equality
$$
k=\emptyset
$$
holds.
First of all, let's we observe that $\mathbf P$ is a functional: indeed, any set $h$ is alway an ordinal calculus or otherthing; moreover, is easy to check that any entity into the above equalities is uniquely determinend. So by transfinite recursion theorem there exists a class-function $\mathbf F$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that the equality
\begin{equation}
\mathbf F=\mathbf G(\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha)
\tag{7}
\label{eq: F value}
\end{equation}
holds for any $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$, where $\mathbf G$ is the class-function corresponding to $\mathbf P$.
Now let's we prove that $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$, with $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$, is a $\alpha$-calculus.
$-----------------------------------$
First of all, let's we assume $\alpha$ is an ordinal such that $\mathbf F\restriction_\beta$ is a $\beta$-calculus for any $\beta$ in $\alpha$ and thus let's we distinguish the following three cases:
(e) $\alpha$ is empty;
(f) $\alpha$ is successor;
(g) $\alpha$ is limit and not empty;
Case (e): In this case $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ is empty so that it will be trivially a $0$-calculus;
Case (f): Let's we assume $\alpha$ is the successor of $\beta$. Now for any $\theta$ in $\alpha$ the inequality
$$
\theta\le\beta
$$
holds so that $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ will be a $\alpha$-calculus wheter $\mathbf F(\beta)$ is an ordinal: indeed by inductive hypotesis $\mathbf F\restriction_\beta$ is a $\beta$-calculus and so $\mathbf F(\gamma)$ is an ordinal for any $\gamma$ in $\beta$; moreover, by replacement axiom $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ is a function -with domain $\alpha$.
So we can consider the following cases:

$\beta$ is empty;
$\beta$ is successor;
$\beta$ is limit.

So if $\beta$ is empty then by eq. \eqref{eq: P zero} and eq. \eqref{eq: F value} the equality
$$
\mathbf F(\beta)=\mathbf G(\mathbf F\restriction_\beta)=\mathbf G(\emptyset)=
\begin{cases}
\xi(0),\text{ if $\xi\neq\emptyset$}\\
\emptyset,\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
holds and thus $\mathbf F(\beta)$ is an ordinal since both $\emptyset$ and $\xi(\emptyset)$ are such. After all, if $\beta$ is the successor of any $\gamma$ then $\mathbf F\restriction_\beta$ is a $(\gamma+1)$-calculus and thus by eq. \eqref{eq: P successive} and eq. \eqref{eq: F value} the equality
$$
\mathbf F(\beta)=
\mathbf G(\mathbf F\restriction_\beta)=
\mathbf G(\mathbf F\restriction_{\gamma+1})=
\begin{cases}
\mathbf F(\gamma)\,\bot\,\,\xi(\gamma+1),\text{ if $\gamma+1<\lambda$}\\
\mathbf F(\gamma),\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
holds: so $\mathbf F(\beta)$ is an ordinal since $\bot$ is an operation  in $\mathbf{Ord}$ or since  $\mathbf F(\gamma)$ is an ordinal by hypothesis. Finally if $\beta$ is limit then $\mathbf F$ is an ordinal calculus with lenght a limit ordinal and thus by eq. \eqref{eq: P limit} and \eqref{eq: F value} the equality
$$
\mathbf F(\beta)=\mathbf G(\mathbf F\restriction_\beta)=\sup_{\gamma\in\beta}\mathbf F(\gamma)
$$
holds: so $\mathbf F(\beta)$ is an ordinal since by hypotesis $\mathbf F(\gamma)$ is an ordinal for any $\gamma$ in $\beta$ and since the supremum of orinals is an ordinal too.
So we conclude that $\mathbf F(\beta)$ is always an ordinal and thus if by replacement axiom $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ is a function (with domain $\alpha$) then it is an $\alpha$-calculus.
Case (g): In this case $\beta+1$ is in $\alpha$ for any $\beta$ in $\alpha$ so that if by inductive hypothesis $\mathbf F\restriction_{\beta+1}$ is an ordinal calculus then $\mathbf F(\beta)$ would be an ordinal: thus by arbitrariness of $\beta$ we conclude that $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ is a $\alpha$-calculus since by replacement axiom it is a function -with domain $\alpha$.
Finally, we conclude that $\mathbf F\restriction_\alpha$ is always a $\alpha$-calculus so that by transfinite induction we conclude that this is true for any ordinal.
$-----------------------------------$
Now by the same argument advanced in (f) it is not hard to conclude equalities eq. \eqref{eq: zero case}-\eqref{eq: limit case} are true; moreover, by eq. \eqref{eq: zero case}-\eqref{eq: limit case} is not hard to conclude that $\mathbf F$ is unique: finally the statement follows taking
$$
\pmb\bot_\xi:=\mathbf F
$$

Now let be $(\alpha_i)_{i\in 2}$ an ordinal sequence of lenght $2$: by eq. \eqref{eq: successive case} we first observe the equality
$$
\pmb\bot_\xi(1)=\pmb\bot_\xi(0+1)=\pmb\bot_\xi(0)\,\bot\,\,\alpha(0+1)=\alpha_0\,\bot\,\,\alpha_1
$$
holds and thus by eq. \eqref{eq: successive case} we conclude even the equality
\begin{equation}
\pmb\bot_\xi(2)=\pmb\bot_\xi(1+1)=\pmb\bot_\xi(1)=\alpha_0\,\bot\,\,\alpha_1
\tag{8}
\label{eq: binary summ}
\end{equation}
holds, since $2$ is not into the domain $(2)$ of $(\alpha_i)_{i\in 2}$. Moreover, by transfinite induction is not hard to show that for any ordinal $\alpha$ the inequality
\begin{equation}
\bot_\emptyset(\alpha)=\emptyset
\tag{9}
\label{eq: empty sum}
\end{equation}
holds;
So if $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\lambda}$ is a transfinite sequence of lenght $\lambda$ then by eq. \eqref{eq: binary summ} and eq. \eqref{eq: empty sum} I put
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in\lambda}\alpha_i:=\pmb +_\alpha(\lambda)
\tag{10}
\label{def: transfinite sum}
\end{equation}
where $+$ is the standard (ordinal) addition; moreover I even put
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i\in\lambda}\alpha_i:=\pmb\ast_\alpha(\lambda)
\tag{11}
\label{def: transfinite product}
\end{equation}
where $\ast$ is the usual (ordinal) multiplication: more generally, if $\Delta$ is any ordinal operation then by eq. \eqref{eq: binary summ} and eq. \eqref{eq: empty sum} I put
\begin{equation}
\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i:=\Delta_\alpha(\lambda)
\tag{12}
\label{def: iterative operation}
\end{equation}
Anyway, attempting to evaluate the "truth" and so the utility of the lemma I observed what to follow.

Observation
Let be $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\omega}$ the $\omega$-calculus with costant value $\omega$: if $\bigwedge$ is the operator correspoding to the ordianl exponentiation $\wedge$ then it seems to me the equality
$$
\bigwedge_{i\in\omega}\alpha_i=\sup_{i\in\omega}\pmb\wedge_\alpha(i)=\sup\left\{\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\dotsc\right\}
$$
holds so that the above lemma allows to give a formal definition of $\epsilon$-number.

However, I was not able to prove or disprove if the usual properties (like monotonicity, linearity, associativity etc...) of sum and product was true for the "transfinite" too; moreover into the textes by Sierpiński and  by Rosenstines I found nothing about: so I thought to put here a question for asking elucidation about; in particular I want know if actually the above lemma give is consinstet first with the finite summ of ordinals and then with the transfinite; finally I ask if the usual properties of sum and product are actually true for transfinite sum and product and so where I can found the corresponding proof.
Anyway giving an example, about monotonicity I tried what to follow but there is an issue as I will explain but firstly, let's we give the following definition.

Definition
Let be $\bot$ an ordinal operation: we say that $\bot$ is pseudomonotone on the left if the statment
$$
(\forall\alpha)
\left(
(\alpha\in\mathbf{Ord})\to
\Biggl(
(\forall\beta)
\biggl(
(\beta\in\alpha)\to
\Big(
(\forall\lambda)
\big(
(\lambda\in\mathbf{Ord})\to(\lambda\,\bot\,\alpha\le\lambda\,\bot\,\beta)
\big)
\Big)
\biggl)
\Biggl)
\right)
$$
holds; moreover, we say that $\bot$ is pseudomonotone on the right if the statment
$$
(\forall\alpha)
\left(
(\alpha\in\mathbf{Ord})\to
\Biggl(
(\forall\beta)
\biggl(
(\beta\in\alpha)\to
\Big(
(\forall\lambda)
\big(
(\lambda\in\mathbf{Ord})\to(\alpha\,\bot\,\lambda\le\beta\,\bot\,\lambda)
\big)
\Big)
\biggl)
\Biggl)
\right)
$$
holds; finally we simply say that $\bot$ is pseudomonotone if the both the above statment hold.

Now by well know results we know that the standard sum and the standard multiplication are pseudomonotone so that let's we investigate what is about "transfinite" sum and product: on this purpuse we formulate first the foollowing conjecture.

Conjecture
If $\Delta$ is an ordinal operation then for any ordinal sequence $\alpha$ of lenght $\lambda$ the equality
\begin{equation}
\underset{i\in(\delta+1)}{\Delta}\alpha_i=\left(\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i\right)\Delta\,\alpha_\delta
\tag{13}
\label{eq: conjecture successive}
\end{equation}
holds, wheter $\delta$ is such that $\delta+1$ is strictly less than $\lambda$; moreover, if $\lambda$ is limit the equality
\begin{equation}
\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\alpha_i=\sup_{\delta\in\lambda}\left(\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i\right)
\tag{14}
\label{eq: conjecture limit}
\end{equation}
holds.

So, let's we prove the following proposition, assuming the above conjecture is true.

Proposition
If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two transfinite sequences of ordinals with length $\lambda$ such that the statment
$$
(\forall i)
\big(
(i\in\lambda)\to(\alpha_i\le\beta_i)
\big)
$$
holds then for any pseudomonotone ordinal operation $\Delta$ the inequality
$$
\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\alpha_i\le\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\beta_i
$$
holds.
Proof.
Let's we proceed by transfinite induction over $\lambda$.
So if $\lambda$ is empty then the statment by eq. \eqref{eq: empty sum} trivially holds;
Now if $\lambda$ is the successor of any ordinal $\delta$ then we know the inequality
$$
\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i\le\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\beta_i
$$
holds: thus by pseudomonotonicity even the inequality
$$
\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\alpha_i=\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i\,\bot\,\alpha_\delta\le\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\beta_i\,\bot\,\alpha_\delta\le\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\beta_i\,\bot\,\beta_\delta=\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\beta_i
$$
Finally if $\lambda$ is limit then we know for any $\delta$ in $\lambda$ the inequality
$$
\underset{i\in\delta}{\alpha_i}\le\underset{i\in\delta}{\beta_i}
$$
holds so that by (ordinal) transitivity even the inclusion
$$
\underset{i\in\delta}{\alpha_i}\subseteq\underset{i\in\delta}{\beta_i}
$$
holds: thus taking the union we conclude the inclusion
$$
\bigcup_{\delta\in\lambda}\underset{i\in\delta}{\alpha_i}\subseteq\bigcup_{\delta\in\lambda}\underset{i\in\delta}{\beta_i}
$$
holds so that (by a well know result) the inequality
$$
\underset{i\in\lambda}{\Delta}\alpha_i=\sup_{\delta\in\lambda}\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\alpha_i\le\sup_{\delta\in\lambda}\underset{i\in\delta}{\Delta}\beta_i=\Delta_{i\in\lambda}\beta_i
$$
holds.
Finally by transfinite induction we conclude that the statment holds.

So unfortunately I was not really able to prove eq. \eqref{eq: conjecture successive}-\eqref{eq: conjecture limit} consistentely with def. \eqref{def: iterative operation}.

I’ll answer your question on math.se — voting to close here as I think it’s better suited there.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine First of all, thanks for your interest. Anyway, if you believe, I can delete or close the question here: in this case do you think I have to edit the question on math.se putting what I put here now?

I’ve written my answer to address the question as written there.  Hopefully it will also help you see how to address your concerns about monotonicity, but if not, I suggest asking that as a separate followup question there.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Firstly, I thank you very much for the answer on math.se. Actually, you answered to the question on math.se since there I only asked to explain if my approach aligns with the standard practices. Well, by this I think I am inclined to accept your answer; then, as you suggested, I will pose another regarding monotonicity.

P.S.
Upon checking on Jech's text book  (that named Set Theory and edited by Springer) and more briefly on Kunen's one I could not find anything about the transfinite series of ordinal or of order types.

Finally, before to approve the answer (on math.se) only one last confirmation, since my comprehension about English language is not the strongest: keeping in mind what I read on the textes I here mentioned, you stated (into the answer) that my approach agrees not only with the standard sum (and product) of a finite sequence of order types but even with that of a transfinite sequence, correct?

Yes, I did mean that.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Perfect: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks really much for your assistance! :-)
